# Run continuous `demo( )` with timer for changes between events

Tags: r, time, presentation, demo

Lets say I am running `demo(graphics)` and I want to control the speed with which consecutive plots are displayed. Normally when I run `demo(graphics)` I can control when the next plot will display by pressing enter (and this way triggering next function in `demo()`). But I don't want to press enter - I want it to run on its own, with the time-controlled changes between plot displays (for example the plot would change every 6 seconds, next after 3 seconds, etc.). Below is a *brutal* code that changes between two `demo()` functions after 2 seconds. I also run `demo()` in *quick-mode* using `echo=FALSE`. But I would like to do that WITHIN a single `demo()` (and for the `example()` too if possible).

```
  library(tcltk2)
  test1 <- function() demo(graphics,echo=F)
  test2 <- function() demo(lm.glm, package="stats",echo=F)
  tclTaskSchedule(2000, test1())
  Sys.sleep(2)
  tclTaskSchedule(2000, test2())
  Sys.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply set `before.plot.new` hook to add delays:

```
setHook("before.plot.new", function(...) Sys.sleep(1))
demo(graphics, ask=F)
```